# Behaviour of sort in lists joined with equality

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Can someone explain the below:

```
fruits = ["banana", "orange", "grape"]
slice = fruits
print fruits==(slice.sort())
print fruits==slice
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Why is the first one `False`?

Comment: In what way is it puzzling you? Remember that in-place sort returns `None`, so the first equality comparison would be false.

Comment: user3309719 I took some liberties rewording your question to make it a better fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` sorts a list **in place** and returns `None`. In the first comparison, `fruits` is not `None`, so `False` is returned. In the second comparison, since `fruits` and `slice` point to the same object, `True` must be returned.

Answer (score 0):

While @Mureinik has stated the in-place sort function returns `None` and all is good, the real question is: why is `fruits == slice` true when `fruits` should be unsorted and `slice` is the only one sorted?

This might be a lot of information, but bear with me...

## `slice = fruits` doesn't result in a new list being created, only a new reference

After you sort `slice`, `fruits` shouldn't be equal to `slice`, but it turned out it did. Why is that? It's because *`slice` and `fruit` refer to the same object*. When you assigned `slice` to `fruit`, you only made a connection to it, and whatever happens to one of them happens to both of them.

In Python, you can check whether variables refer to the same object with the `is` operator. Note that this is different from `==` which just checks whether the *contents* are the same, not the memory location:

```
>>> fruits = ["banana", "orange", "grape"]
>>> slice = fruits
>>> fruits is slice
True
>>> fruits == slice
False
```

Think of it as this way. Whatever OS you use, you can create desktop shortcuts of a file. But it merely *links* to the real file. But just like how you can copy and paste things around to create separate files independent of the original, you can do that too in Python. I know two ways to do so.

1. Use `list(...)`

   ```
   >>> fruits = ["banana", "orange", "grape"]
   >>> slice = list(fruits)  # constructs a new list and copies content
   >>> fruits is slice
   False
   >>> slice is fruits
   False
   >>> fruits == slice
   True
   ```
2. Use `copy.copy(...)`

   ```
   >>> from copy import copy
   >>> fruits = ["banana", "orange", "grape"]
   >>> slice = copy(fruits)  # copies to new list
   >>> fruits is slice
   False
   >>> slice is fruits
   False
   >>> fruits == slice
   True
   ```

## An *in-place* operation modifies the object being passed and doesn't return anything (`None`)

Back to what is the problem: an in-place sort, which was done with `list.sort()`, means that no new object was created and you modified the original. That is why the function doesn't return anything - it doesn't need to because it changed the original content. It just returns `None` and as @Mureinik has stated, `fruits` was never `None` at any point.

A quick demo:

```
>>> fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'grape']
>>> fruits = fruits.sort()
>>> fruits  # not going to print anything
>>> fruits is None
True
>>> fruits == None
True
```

Now, when you did an in-place sort by modifying the contents of `slice`, you also modified the contents of `fruits`, because they referred to the object one and the same. There was only one object that was created and manipulated.

## You can create a new sorted list with `sorted()`

Yes, you can sort a list by creating a new list.

```
>>> fruits = ["banana", "orange", "grape"]
>>> slice = fruits
>>> slice  # still referring to same object
["banana", "orange", "grape"]
>>> slice = sorted(slice)  # creates a new list, and sorts it
>>> slice  # it's not None because the above returns a new object
["banana", "grape", "orange"]
>>> fruits  # not modified at all
["banana", "orange", "grape"]
>>> fruits == slice
False
>>> fruits.sort()
>>> fruits
["banana", "grape", "orange"]
>>> fruits is slice
False
>>> fruits == slice
True
```

Alternatively, you can also create a new list first, and then do the in-place sort:

```
>>> fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'grape']
>>> slice = list(fruits)  # don't refer to same object
>>> slice.sort()
>>> slice
["banana", "grape", "orange"]
>>> fruits
['banana', 'orange', 'grape']
```